# Export Visual Studio Setup project to NSIS (NSIS Importer)

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, nsis, setup-deployment

I have a setup/deployment project that I've built in Visual Studio for packaging my WPF app. I now want to build an installer in NSIS for packaging my app. Is there any tool through which I can import my VS setup project into NSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only import tool NSIS has is for .reg files AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool called `SetupProjects Converter` from `unSigned` that does exactly that:

https://www.visual-installer.com/free-tools.html